# advice with php date and timestamps

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp

We have a battle system where people can pick a match time to challenge another player. To create a match the user needs to pick a date. Currently a user picks the day, hour, minute, and pm/am from a dropdown list. If the user selects 5/20/2012 @ 1PM, the system adds the hours and minutes from the start of the day. Here's a quick sample to get a better understanding of what I'm talking about:

```
$time = strtotime('today', $inputdate);
$time = $time + $hours + $minutes;
```

the value of `$hours` changes if the users selects AM or PM. It's pretty basic: 
[image: sample]

Everything was working fine until people started have timezone issues. For example, if player A creates a match at 1:PM, then player B will see the match starts at 1:PM, but he/she will have different timezones!

The problem is that I don't know the problem :/

I don't know how to fix the timezone issue. I have been creating functions in the hopes that everything will fall together, but no luck.

What I have:

- User profiles have a timezone options.
- A function that gets the raw timestamp and returns the formatted time based on the user's timezone.
- A function that gets a timestamp and converts it to another timestamp
  based on the user's timezone.

I'm lost and I can't seem to fix the issue, I can code, but right now I'm not thinking logical. I took me one hour to write this and try to explain it how I could, since I myself don't know how to make it work. Some advice is appreciated.

I need a function to convert a timestamp to UTC-5:

```
function input_date($timestamp)
{
    global $vbulletin;
    $timestamp = (int)$timestamp;

    if (strlen((string)$timestamp) == 10)
    {
        $hour = 3600.00;
        $offset = $vbulletin->userinfo['timezoneoffset'];//sample -8
        $ds = (int)$vbulletin->userinfo['dstonoff'];//DST
        $fluff = $hour*($offset+5.00);
        $timestamp = $timestamp+$fluff+($ds*$hour);

        return $timestamp;//return timestamp in UTC-5 format..
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Store all the data in a consistent timezone (UTC should be the one to go for). Then make your computations from and to the user's timezone only at the point of displaying it to them.

Comment: would it make a difference if I store it as another timezone?

Comment: No but it might make you go slowly insane :-) If you store a UNIX timestamp (i.e. the result of strtotime), then you're storing without timezone information.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially everything in the database should be stored using a single timezone, preferably one which is not affected by DST. The standard option here is UTC.

If you know the user's timezone by its name, you can use that to generate your time:

```
// Player A creates match at 1PM Europe/London
$timezone = 'Europe/London';
$localTime = '2012-03-01 13:00:00';

// work out UNIX timestamp using that timezone (making it timezone independent)
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
$timestamp = strtotime($localTime);

// store $timestamp in the database

// Player B views the timestamp with timezone America/Los_Angeles
$timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';

date_default_timezone_set($timezone);
var_dump(date('c', $timestamp)); // see manual for more output formats
```

If you have the timezones stored as their abbreviations (e.g. "CET", "GMT"), then use `timezone_name_from_abbr` to get the correct timezone name.

Comment: I don't get this code. I know the user's timezone by offset only, like: if the user is in LA, the offset/timezone would be -8 (that's how the system is setup).

Comment: Shouldn't be too difficult to handle, but it won't always be perfect (i.e. are they UTC -8 because they're in LA, or in Alaska during daylight savings time?) Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286281/converting-timezone-offset-to-friendly-name-in-php) for info on the best way to get a timezone name from the UTC offset.

Comment: The system has the user's DST too, so that' not the problem. I now know the issue, the issue is that I need to convert a timestamp to UTC -5 (server time). I don't know how to do that...I update my Q hopefully u can help out a bit.

Comment: OK, so from that you can figure out the timezone name. Then using date_default_timezone_set as above, any dates are formatted / parsed using that timezone. See http://codepad.org/DVFrKgFk for an example of the above.

Comment: I cannot use your method because I use vbulletin and their API is limited. I posted a new Questions to narrow down the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526939/assistance-with-a-timestamp-php-function

Comment: Why can the above not be used in this case? The above is native PHP. The presence of vBulletin does not prevent the ability to use these functions. Using a timezone name is the safest way to get the correct formatted timestamp. UNIX timestamps have no consideration of timezone (they're all UTC), so your second question still might give you problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8422/discussion-between-user962449-and-cbuckley)